# Set printer security binary key in registry via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, printing, registry

I have been struggling on how to set Security on a printer object in 2008 R2. Was super nice on a 2012 machine and want to do something similar on 2008 R2 but am failing.

I wrote a function to get the value of that registry, and then a secondary function to set the value on a different printer but its not accepting the value.

Had anticipated manually setting values on a printer to get permissions as needed then read from that and set to handful of other newly added printers.

It responds stating the following error.

```
"The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted."
```

Here is my test code I am fumbling with.

```
$ComputerName = "TESTSERVER01"

Function Get-RegistryString {
Param(
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [string]$KeyPath,
    [string]$KeyName,
    [string]$KeyValue
    )

$KeyValueType = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String

try {
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $ComputerName )
    $regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($KeyPath, $True)
    $regKey.GetValue($KeyName) 

    } catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        $error.Clear()
        return $false 
    }
}

Function Set-RegistryBinary {
Param(
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [string]$KeyPath,
    [string]$KeyName,
    [string]$KeyValue
    )

$KeyValueType = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::Binary

try {
    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $ComputerName )
    $regKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($KeyPath, $True)
    $regKey.SetValue($KeyName, $KeyValue, $KeyValueType) 

    } catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        $error.Clear()
        return $false 
    }
}


$SecKey = Get-RegistryString -ComputerName $ComputerName -KeyPath "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Printers\\W-TEST01" -KeyName "Security"

Set-RegistryBinary -ComputerName $ComputerName -KeyPath "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Printers\\W-TEST02" -KeyName "Security" -KeyValue $SecKey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simply the line `[string]$KeyValue`. You are casting a byte array to a string which wrecks the data for the next step. All I needed to do to get this to work is remove the cast. Could also change the cast to `[byte[]]$KeyValue` and I think it would work as well.

```
Function Set-RegistryBinary {
Param(
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [string]$KeyPath,
    [string]$KeyName,
    [byte[]]$KeyValue$KeyValue
    )
```

You can see an example of what is happening here. First I just create a byte array. Then using the same array construction I cast it to a string.

```
PS C:\Users\Cameron> [byte[]](1,134,233,5)
1
134
233
5

PS C:\Users\Cameron> [string]([byte[]](1,134,233,5))
1 134 233 5
```

Casting any array to a string will do something *similar* to snippet above.

Comment: Thanks! - Nice solid response and example to help spell it out. I actually had to cast it as a byte array for it to work, simply removing the string casting failed.